# Looking for a nonUEFI motherboard

Tags: motherboard, linux, desktop, security

I'm looking for a motherboard that does **not** have UEFI. So far I been been unable to find any. It is for a system that will be running a bare bones Debian or Gentoo system. Its speed and compatibility with newer hardware are secondary as long as it only has BIOS. Looking to make it very difficult for malware to survive a full system wipe. I have no other hardware requirements (ie chipset, max memory, etc.) except that it be ddr3 compatible and newer than 2000.